# Info from two sql tables to one HTML table

Tags: php, html, mysql, mysqli

I Have tables like invoice & expenses output looks like this:

invoice
[image]

expenses:
[image]

How I can display these two tables in on table ordered by date ( Kuupäev)
with my example first row must by from expenses 01-02-2015
next from invoice 14-08-2015 / 16-08-2015 / 16-08-2015 and then from expenses 17-08-2015

when invoice query is:

```
     $results = $mysqli->query(" SELECT * FROM tulu T1 
  INNER JOIN artikkel A1 on T1.artikkel_id = A1.artikkel_id 
  INNER JOIN liige L1 on T1.liige_id = L1.liige_id
  INNER JOIN maksja M1 on T1.maksja_id = M1.maksja_id
  ORDER BY kuup2ev ;
```

And table displayed with code:

```
print '<table class="mytable4">';
echo "<tr><th>Kuupäev </th><th>Artikkel </th><th>Maksja </th><th>Summa</th><th>Kommentaar</th><th>Sisestaja</th></tr>";
while($row = $results->fetch_array()) {
$timestamp = strtotime($row['kuup2ev']);

 print '<tr>';
  print '<td>'.$date = date('d-m-Y', $timestamp).'</td>';
   print '<td>'.$row["a_nimi"].'</td>';
    print '<td>'.$row["m_nimi"].'</td>';
    print '<td>'.$row["summa"].'</td>';
    print '<td>'.$row["kommentaar"].'</td>';
    print '<td>'.$row["nimi"].'</td>';
 print '</tr>';
}  
print '</table>';
```

The expenses query is:

```
SELECT * FROM kulu K1 
  INNER JOIN artikkel A1 on K1.artikkel_id = A1.artikkel_id 
  INNER JOIN liige L1 on K1.liige_id = L1.liige_id
  ORDER BY kuup2ev ;
```

sql tables:
expenses
[image]

invoice
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use UNION ALL like:

```
SELECT * FROM (
  (SELECT tulu_id, null as kulu_id, kuup2ev, artikkel_id, maksja_id, null as kogus, summa, kommentaar, liige_id, staatus, timestamp FROM tulu)
  UNION ALL
  (SELECT null as tulu_id, kulu_id, kuup2ev, artikkel_id, null as maksja_id, kogus, summa, kommentaar, liige_id, staatus, timestamp FROM kulu)
ORDER BY kuup2ev) T1
INNER JOIN artikkel A1 on T1.artikkel_id = A1.artikkel_id 
INNER JOIN liige L1 on T1.liige_id = L1.liige_id
LEFT JOIN maksja M1 on T1.maksja_id = M1.maksja_id
```

PS: Please correct the column name when trying this query.

Comment: In Tables are different columns or in invoice have two extra columns

Comment: Alright, I didn't notice but you can still use union all by creating empty column in select query where it is missing. For example, use `SELECT *, null as Kongus FROM tulu...` in first select query and `SELECT *, null as Maksja FROM kulu...` in second query etc to equal the columns.

Comment: PS: please use the appropriate column names in comment above. Also you can adjust your join statements's position to join these tables to union output directly.

Comment: my phpMyAdmin give result: #1222 - The used SELECT statements have a different number of columns, I added SQL table examples in post

Comment: alright, based on given information that is all I can say. Please post both tables' structure here or otherwise please check each table individually and add fictitious columns in select statement of other table for both select statement.

Comment: also instead of using * to select columns, use explicit column names in each select table. this will make the difference more clear and easy to fix.

Comment: I've updated query and it uses correct column names now. Please, try updated query.

Comment: still, same phpMyAdmin console give: "#1222 - The used SELECT statements have a different number of columns "

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/99518/discussion-between-limexs-and-margus).